Can snowflake sproc decorator support passing of argument names? Currently I see sp's are getting created with argument names as arg1, arg2 etc
I have defined my sp through a python file in my application as below
           name="CLEAN_TABLES", is_permanent=True,
           stage_location="@my_stage",
           packages=["snowflake-snowpark-python==1.23.0"],
           replace=True)
    def handle(session: Session,
               input_table_name,
               perm_table_name,
               output_table_name):
        .....

Running above py file is creating sp as below in snowflake account with argument names as ARG1, ARG2 etc
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
MY_SF_DB.my_stage.CLEAN_TABLES(
"ARG1" VARCHAR(11111111), 
"ARG2" VARCHAR(22222222), 
"ARG3" VARCHAR(33333333))

I want the sp to be created with argument names as input_table_name, perm_table_name, output_table_name as specified in the handle function arguments. This helps the user who calls sp's to pass the tables in that order.
